# How to get virtualenv for compiled python (missing pip/easy_install)?

Tags: installation, python, source, virtualenv

To update an old system I had to compile python 2.7.14 with custom openssl version. The compiled system has no virtualenv binary and also neither pip nor easy_install for extension. How can I get virtualenv for the compiled version? How about pip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs on installing packages at https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#ensure-you-can-run-pip-from-the-command-line there is a section on ensuring pip by running

```
/path_to_compiled_python/bin/python -m ensurepip --default-pip
```

which will install pip. You can then use it to install the virtualenv package with

```
/path_to_compiled_python/bin/pip install virtualenv
```

Answer (score 0):

The steps that helped to setup a custom version of Python with a virtual environment without doing system wide installation.

**Install dependencies:**

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libssl-dev openssl g++ # and possibly more.
```

**Get Python and build it:**

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.8/Python-3.8.8.tgz
tar xzvf Python-3.8.8.tgz
cd Python-3.8.8
./configure
make
```

**Install "pip" to "~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages":**

```
./python -m ensurepip --default-pip
./python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

**Setup the virtual environment:**

```
# Creates a directory "./python3.8-env".
./python -m venv python3.8-env
```

**Activate the virtual environment and install other packages.**

```
source python3.8-env/bin/activate
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install <package>
```